# Backbone.js without REST using ASP .net webservice

Tags: javascript, asp.net, backbone.js

(sorry for the english)

I have a ASP .net webservice that get data from a oracle database returning JSON data.

```
TestWebService.asmx/getUserData
```

I test this using simply ajax request with jQuery

```
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     data:"{}",
     dataType:"json",
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url:"TestWebService.asmx/getUserData",
     success:function(data){
         console.log(data.d);
     }
});
```

This work.

But now i want to try use Backbone.js

The Application have this: User data, Articles and Buy Order where a Buy order is a collection of Articles, so i think in this models for Backbone

```
User = Backbone.Model.extend({})
Article = Backbone.Model.extend({})
ArticleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
BuyOrder = Backbone.Model.extend({})
BuyOrderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
```

The Views are just 2. A Form where i show the User Data and inputs to add Articles and create the Buy Order and a Visualize view to show the Buy Orders where the user can see an check the content of one buy order clicking in the code.

The UserData, and part of the Article Data are get from the service: (User Data like name and Article Data like code, description, price, etc).

¿How can i populate the Backbone models with this data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, basically, you want to override `Backbone.sync`.  It is the thing that is currently doing your RESTful stuff (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) via the `$.ajax` function as well.  See how it is implemented by default: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-134

As you can tell, it is really quite simple... about 30 or so lines of code to map create/update/delete/read to post/put/delete/get in `$.ajax`.

Now that you have seen how they do it, you just implement your own using the same pattern:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    // your implementation
};
```

Once you do that, you are golden.  Your models will do all the CRUD that you want them to, abstracted through your implementation of `Backbone.sync`.

Comment: An asmx endpoint looks no different than the url a Backbone collection expects. The OP could simply `col.fetch({ url:'TestWebService.asmx/getUserData' })` for example.

Comment: So just override Backbone.sync would do the trick to populate the Backbone Models on start (defaults data) and for use for example with autocomplete (from jQuery-UI) and so on?...

Comment: Yes, but like @Crescent Fresh suggested, did you try using your endpoint as the URL?  I wouldn't call fetch with a URL like that as it doesn't encapsulate things... but I'd put `url: 'TestWebService.asmx/getUserData'` in the definition of the collection.  Assuming you need to do more than the default `Backbone.sync` does, then you should override it.  If the default works for you, just specify the `url` property of the collection.

Comment: If your backend requires POST in order to *get* user data, the default sync will not work, as it (correctly) uses GET for get operations http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-123

Comment: @dira Right.  I remember seeing that now.  If "read" needs to map to "POST" then you will need to override the default `Backbone.sync`.

Comment: @Brian, @dira: The `type` option can be passed in as `'post'` with the options to `fetch()` (or `sync()` for that matter). If passing data, `$.param()` or `JSON.stringify` can be used to stringify it.

Comment: @RoatinMarth Although, I agree that there are all sorts of parameters you can pass into the sync layer, I don't think that is the correct approach.  In order to make the models/collections fit the simple save/fetch semantics, you would need to override all or the models/collections to handle it.  You could, of course, create base classes to make this work, but I feel like an override to `Backbone.sync` is the appropriate way to handle transport-level changes.  That way, all models/collections get it. Overriding Model/Collection is better suited for data-level changes (like overriding parse).

Comment: @Brian: agreed. For me it came down to an implementation detail: in one collection only, an array parameter needed to be passed by `fetch` that busted IIS query string limit. So in that one collection only, fetch was overridden to set `type` to `'post'` to avoid the error. No other collection needed to have this behaviour.